# Why is my replication of Silver & Dunlap 1987 not working out?

Tags: r, correlation, data-transformation, simulation, normalization

I'm trying to replicate [Silver & Dunlap (1987)](http://www.mendeley.com/research/averaging-correlation-coefficients-should-fishers-z-transformation-be-used/).  I'm just comparing averaging correlations or averaging z transform correlations and back transforming.  I seem to not be replicating the asymmetry in the bias they find (back transformed zs are not closer to the population value for me than rs).  Any thoughts?  Is it possible that 1987 computing power just didn't explore the space enough?

```
# Fisher's r2z
fr2z <- atanh
# and back
fz2r <- tanh

# a function that generates a matrix of two correlated variables
rcor <- function(n, m1, m2, var1, var2, corr12){
    require(MASS)
    Sigma <- c(var1, sqrt(var1*var2)*corr12, sqrt(var1*var2)*corr12, var2)
    Sigma <- matrix(Sigma, 2, 2)
    return( mvrnorm(n, c(m1,m2), Sigma, empirical=FALSE) )
    }
```

With these function it's easy to look at a bunch of correlations (basically replicate silver and dunlap 1987) and see the difference between averaging correlations and averaging z-scores and back transforming.  Here's just one.

```
r <- 0.9
Y <- replicate(20000, rcor(10, 0, 0, 1, 1, r))
rs <- apply(Y, 3, function(x) cor(x[,1], x[,2]))
mean(rs) - r
zs <- fr2z(rs)
fz2r( mean(zs) ) - r
```

Just looking at the sample size of 10 and correlations of 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9 these are the results.

```
     rho  r bias   z bias
     0.1  -0.006   0.006
     0.5  -0.024   0.021
     0.9  -0.011   0.011
```

And these are derived from Table 1 of Silver & Dunlap.

```
     rho  r bias   z bias
     0.1  -0.007   0.003
     0.5  -0.025   0.001
     0.9  -0.011  -0.007
```

These are quite different results.  From my test I'm seeing that it's just a matter of direction of bias, not magnitude.  But, in the published paper they're finding much less magnitude with z.  I couldn't find a published non-replication.

Comment: I'm stuck at your first two lines.  They do not appear to be correct R syntax.  They also appear to assume that atanh is its own inverse, but it's not: tanh is the inverse of atanh.

Comment: They're just typos in the question... fixed.

Comment: Thanks.  There still must be some typos: for instance, what does a margin of 3 mean in "apply"?  It would be nice if you could double-check that the code you posted actually performs as you expect.

Comment: To me, just by eye, the `r bias` for `rho` of 0.5 in the Silver & Dunlap table looks like the outlier to me. I certainly can't vouch for the quality of the journal, which appears quite new and a bit rough around the edges, but I did find this [recent paper](https://journals.uair.arizona.edu/index.php/jmmss/article/view/114) with a Google search. See, in particular, their Table 3 which, again, by eye, appears to corroborate your results.

Comment: I don't have ready access to the S&D paper, but the abstract raises some intriguing possibilities concerning what should be meant by "bias."  There is no question that the histogram of the r's is skewed (just execute `hist(rs)`) and that of the z's is not (`hist(zs)`).  But this does *not* necessarily imply that the mean of independent realizations of $r$ will be a biased estimator of $\rho$!

Comment: @whuber: Quite true. However, the UMVUE of $\rho$ in the bivariate normal case---as you may very well know---is (fairly) well-known to be $$ r \frac{\Gamma((n-2)/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma((n-3)/2)}\int_0^1 \frac{u^{-1/2} (1-u)^{(n-5)/2}}{\sqrt{1-u(1-r^2)}} \,\mathrm{d}u \>.$$ Here $r$ is the MLE. Sometimes this estimator appears under the notation $G(r)$.

Comment: Thanks John--I had been wondering about that (and the standard help page for `apply` is of no use about this matter).  Unfortunately, your code as posted didn't work for me (R x64 2.11.1): it raised various errors.  I made it work by computing correlations within the `replicate` loop.

Comment: whuber, the margin 3 is correct in apply().  The apply() command can be used on an array of any number of dimensions.  The variable Y contains a 3 dimensional array of matrices.  The first two dimensions are those of one matrix and the third is the number of matrices generated.  So, the apply() command is going across the matrices and getting the correlations of the two columns.  After editing that first error you noted everything worked.

Comment: And thank you, @Cardinal.  The issue I was trying to raise is that it's unclear from the abstract just what question the S&D paper is addressing and what it means by "bias."  I guess it comes down to why one would want to average correlations in the first place.  (I have never found that to be a good solution to any statistical problem I encountered, but that could merely reflect the kinds of problems I have focused on.)

Comment: To quote the paper... after explaining the analytic solution to the negative and positive bias of the zs and rs they state... "What is not known is the statistical behavior of an averaged z, backtransformed to the form of r."

Comment: @whuber: You raise good points. I didn't have ready access to the S&D paper either, so my remarks have been reduced to conjecture. If we ever happen to meet in person, I'll swap a story or two with you over a beer on the frustrations of dealing with those who insist on averaging correlations. I agree wholeheartedly with your comments on the matter. That said, it may make sense in some settings that I'm generally less familiar with. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me, the `r bias` entry for `rho` of 0.5 in the Silver & Dunlap table looks the most suspiciously different to me. However, that said, it *does* match your estimated value quite closely.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Silver & Dunlap paper at the moment, but a Google search did turn up a recent paper that performs a similar study to the one you've done. It is

> R. L. Gorsuch and C. S. Lehmann (2010), [Correlation coefficients: Mean bias and confidence interval distortions](https://journals.uair.arizona.edu/index.php/jmmss/article/view/114), *Journal of Methods and Measurement in the Social Sciences*, vol. 1, no. 2, 52–65.

See, in particular, their Table 3 which, at least by eye, appears to corroborate your results.

I certainly can't vouch for the quality of the journal (or the whole paper), which looks quite new and a bit rough around the edges, in my estimation. Caveat lector.

For an in-depth, more theoretical, treatment of inference on correlation (simple, partial, and multiple) primarily in a multivariate normal framework, a good reference is

> F. A. Graybill, *[Theory and application of the linear model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534380190)*, Duxbury Press, 1976, **Chapter 11**.

It does not concern itself much with small-sample performance or applied aspects, though.